# Deploying IMP-based eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, imp

I have a plugin for my own programming language for eclipse. 
The plugin is based on IMP.
When running the project via "Run as eclipse application" everything works as expected:
I have an eclipse perspective of the language, I can compile/run files associated with my language.
I tried getting the plugin into a clean eclipse install: 
 - I've created a feature project for my plugin 
 - I've created an update site project 
 - I've added my feature, the IMP runtime and the LPG runtime to my update site 
 - I've made sure to synchronize and build-all in the update site. 
 - I've tried "install new software" in the clean eclipse - no errors.

When I run my new eclipse, I cannot see the perspective of my language.
Eclipse doesn't associate my files with any language / perspective.

Please advise!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that there was some kind of error that prevented your plugin from running.  Here are some things you can look at:

1. The error log.  Window -> Show view -> Error log
2. The plugin registry view.  Look for your plugin and make sure it can be `start`ed
3. Start Eclipse with the OSGi console enabled.  You can run some diagnostic commands to see what happens when your bundle is started (run `eclipse -console` to get the OSGi console on the command line)

Comment: The only error in the view was "no language support for text/file ..." for my new language.
My plugin was not started, but I could start it from the registry view and the osgi console.
I ran 'diag' on my plugin - no errors found.
Even after starting my plugin - no perspective.

Comment: The "no language support for text/file" sounds like the error that is preventing your plugin from working.  It must be because there is some file missing from the distribution or that there is a plugin in your distribution that needs to be exploded and it's not.

Comment: This error apparently only appears because I had a file in my language in the workspace. With a blank workspace - no errors.